# What if there are two isolated people playing the Monty hall game?

Tags: probability

There is another [Monte Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) question like this on stack but it doesn't answer the part where  there are two isolated contestants. I'm unconvinced that if 2 people playing the game (isolated from each other) when re-offered the choice should switch the doors they've chosen, i.e., should both of them switch doors and still expect an increase in probability?(It seems to me that if they've made different initial choices(which is more often than not) one of them shouldn't switch and the other should)). Also is there an even better strategy if the contestant switches his choice sometimes and if he doesn't other times?

If it's possible can someone do the case where there are m people playing the game and n doors(n>m)?

Comment: It is important to be clear on exactly what question you're asking - are you conditioning on the two contestants choosing different doors, or are you merely saying that this will happen sometimes (i.e., you are not conditioning on it)?  These kinds of conditions can change the probabilities and thus change the answer to this type of question.

Comment: No, I've never said anywhere I'm conditioning the two contestants choosing different doors, I just said its more likely that they choose different doors

Comment: @Ben Actually, they are blinded to each other's choices by assumption, so no information is lost or gained.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  In its current state this question is just an open invitation to rehash the Monty Hall problem.  Since the salient characteristic of that problem is to create controversy (in no small part due to the possibility of different interpretations of the game), it is unsuitable for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes, they should all switch. Slightly longer answer, their initial choices, whether or not the good prize has a different position in the two cases, was not behind the door that was opened, that is, their initial probability was 1/3, when the third door is already eliminated, their second choice is more likely to be correct, but they have to take that choice to actuate that newer probability. This works for $n$ doors when reduced to $n-1$ doors as well. Concerning the fact that the choices are blinded, that does not reduce information, they cannot see through the doors and not even not knowing which door is which changes nothing, just the change in likelihood is applicable, not actual order in which the doors are aligned. That is, door 1,2,3 has the same predicted initial likelihood as door 2,1,3 and if 3 is opened, all that is important is to switch from either door 2 to 1 or from door 1 to 2.

To be clear, all the contestants have to know is to say "switch doors".

Comment: What do you think happens if the contestants are allowed to speak to each other after they've switched doors and then again offered the choice to switch doors again? Then do the probabilities become 1/2 and 1/2(unless the door revealed to them in the initial offer was each others doors, in which case they can both determine the car)? because now they both know what each other know

Comment: Too complicated for a simple answer in that secondary case. Did they choose the same door, did Monte Hall open the same door for each of them, is it the same competition, or were are there two separate competitions with the prize location changed?

Comment: BTW, not 1/2 for the second $p$, but 2/3's.